# How to use React Context's with Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint, react-context

In my application, I'm trying to use React Context's with `setState`.

```
const userContext = React.createContext([{ user: {} }, () => {}]);
const userHook = useState({ user: {} });

<userContext.Provider value={userHook}>
// some other code here
</userContext.Provider>
```

However, I'm getting this error in my linter: [image].

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Also, when I try to use `React.createContext()` like in many tutorials, e.g.:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext(["green", () => {}]);
```

I get another linter error about an unexpected empty arrow function. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the typings of the context you are creating:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

const userContext = createContext<
  [{ user: {} }, Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ user: {} }>>]
>([{ user: {} }, () => {}]);
```

Now, you won't see any Type error when providing it using:

```
const userHook = useState({ user: {} });
// ...
<userContext.Provider value={userHook}>
  <Foo />
</userContext.Provider>
```

Remember that `userHook` will be an array which you may destructure as:

```
function Foo() {
  const userHook = useContext(userContext);
  const [user, setUser] = userHook // Here, destructuring the array
  return <h1>Foo</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

const userHook = useState({ user: {} }); is wrong. useState returns [state, setState]. Try changing the implementation.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ user: {} });

<userContext.Provider value={state}>
// some other code here
</userContext.Provider>
```

Comment: But won't I not be able to update it since I'm not using a hook? I need to be able to pass `setState` somehow

Comment: I have this code which works:

     const themeHook = useState("darkblue");

    return ( 
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeHook}>
         .... 
    );

but it doesn't work when I use an object.

Comment: You can use the value before it's destructured too.